# How to create link/button which will navigate to a page outside of jquery mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I am trying to create a jQuery mobile link or button which will navigate to another page entirely and not try to assimilate it into its own DOM.

Example:

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-inline="true" >Search</a>
```

In my jQuery mobile page, it performs a transition to the page and applies its renderings.  I want the Google page to show up, as it normally would, not assimilate into the DOM space belonging to the jQuery mobile page.

I want to keep the look and feel of the link/button, yet I want its action to navigate away from the page completely to an entirely new DOM space.  How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add rel="external" to your a tag. This is will notify the DOM that you are leaving the page and not use AJAX navigation.

Like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-inline="true" rel="external">Search</a>
```

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for days. I have scoured the web for why my links weren't behaving as I wanted. And you fixed it.

An upvote is only a small thanks.

Comment: Not a problem @OneManMobile. Glad I could help. Thank you for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-inline="true" rel="external">Search</a>
```